# How can I access my MOTO G3 if I forgot my mobile pattern?

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, motorola-moto-g3

I have forgot my screen lock pattern of my MOTO G3. What do I do now? How can I access my mobile now. If there is any solution, please let me know.

Comment: Eagerly Waiting For Quick Response

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Just make it 3 times and if you not able to open than it will ask you the real password code number, you may just put that number to reset the new password, it doesn't take much time, 2 minutes job, all the best!

Comment: What if internet is off?